# Use htaccess mod_rewrite to hide domain name

Tags: .htaccess

I've read lots about what can be done with mod_rewrite but I haven't found one to solve my problem. Maybe it can't be done?

I have a sub-domain on my primary domain that I have a customer direct user to  to use one of my programs. The customer doesn't want his customers to see that that are on my domain and he doesn't want to use an iframe.

So, is it possible for the user to only see `www.subdomain/program.php` instead of `www.subdomain.mydomain.com/program.php`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser to show `www.subdomain/program.php` in its location bar, you need to register the `www.subdomain` domain name. There is **no way to remove bits of the domain name using anything in the htaccess file**. For example, if you've registered `example.com` and you have a server at `foo.example.com`, and you want to be able to go to `http://foo/some/path/index.html`, you're out of luck because the browser is going to attempt to do a DNS lookup of `foo` and it will most likely fail unless there happens to be a "foo" server under the DNS search domain. Browsers put a great deal of effort to prevent spoofing of the domain name, since it would be really bad if I was able to spoof my website to show the domain of a bank in a browser's location bar while actually visiting an entirely different website.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!